# Slowing down a while loop

Tags: java, eclipse, while-loop

I'm trying to make a while loop in Java but I seems to go to fast. I have searched on stack overflow on how to slow it down. I've found the answer `Thread.sleep(1000);` nested in a try/catch block. But when I tried to run my program the window freezes and I can't shut it down. What am I doing wrong? My code is listed down below.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(new Color(204, 64, 89));

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

        x = (int) (Math.random() * 1001);
        y = (int) (Math.random() * 101);

        while(y < this.getHeight()){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            y++;
            g.fillRect(x, y, 5 ,10);
            repaint();
            System.out.print("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using Swing, see javax.swing.Timer this is what you should use.

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Slow-Down-Loop

Comment: Just take the code you put inside the catch block and put it in any other place.

Comment: I've put the content of the catch block outside of it but it still crashes.

Comment: The javax,swing.Timer didn't work. It just gives me errors now.